# Async.js and Angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript, async.js

I need to execute some promises/callbacks in series in Angular 2.

I know [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async), which is a very nice library to work with asynchronous tasks. And make it easy to deal with this. But I was not able to find an wrapper for typescript.

How could I to se Async library together Angular 2?

Comment: Angular 2 heavily uses Observables, have you tried looking into how to use those instead of trying to use Async? Chaining observables is pretty easy with the `.map` method.

Comment: Angular already uses RxJS, which has more than 60 operators for combining, filtering, mapping, etc. observables. Why not use that?

Comment: By now I know just the basic use of Observables, but I will give a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it if you want, just install typings `npm i @types/async`, `npm i async` and import library:

```
  import async from 'async';
```

Comment: I got the message "Module '"async"' has no exported member 'asyn'". Async is a Javascript library and, to use it on a Angular 2 project, I need an wrapper for typescript.

Answer (score 3):

Install the async package using `npm i --save async` and import it in any component using `import * as async from 'async'`

To get typings for async - `npm i --save-dev @typings/async` and if you structured the project using angular cli, add 'async' to the types array in "src/tsconfig.json"

```
"types":[
  "async"
]
```

For more, refer to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib.